# Failed to open file (Permission denied)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediarecorder

I'm trying to record audio via `MediaRecorder` class in Android, save it in a file and then play it with a `MediaPlayer`.

Here is where I choose the file where I want to save my audio file:

```
currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
condensedDate = currentDate.toString().replaceAll("\\s", "")
fileName = getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
fileName += File.separator + condensedDate + ".3gp";
```

and here I set it as the output file for `MediaRecorder`

```
Recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
```

Then, in another `Activity` I use `MediaPlayer` to play that file audio:

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
try {
     player.setDataSource(fileName);
     player.prepare();
     player.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is where problems begin, nothing is played and this is my Log:

```
09-09 14:31:38.887 1522-26066/? E/FileSource: Failed to open file '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mycompany.dbmeter.pro/cache/SunSep0914:31:19GMT+00:002018.3gp'. (Permission denied)
09-09 14:31:38.887 1522-26066/? E/GenericSource: Failed to create data source!
09-09 14:31:38.887 25996-26064/com.mycompany.dbmeter.pro E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
```

This is strange because I followed step by step the official sample code that can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder#sample-code).

I tried making file world readable as suggested [in this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886921/how-to-create-a-file-with-world-readable-permission-under-subdirectory-of-files).

I also tried what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584657/permission-denied-when-opening-file-that-was-created-in-same-app) but nothing has changed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your manifrst and did you allowed it in your app? seems this cause to permission

Comment: No I don't but I don't think I need it beacuse I save and read other files there without any problem.. Moreover, now it works.. Any idea why that file name could have caused the problem? (see my own answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem, for some reason the name of the file I was using caused that error.

I used to get a date, convert it to a string and eliminate all spaces; something like this:

```
SunSep0914:31:19GMT+00:002018.3gp
```

Now, while debugging my app I changed it to `test.3gp` and it works like a charm...

Comment: I ran into the same problem, your solution worked, but I still want to use ":" in my file name, did you end up finding another solution?

Comment: I ended up changing ":" to "-" because it was the easiest solution for what I needed to do. I think ":" could be one of those characters that you simply cannot use in a file name

Comment: just found out the same in Huawei P20. There were no problems in any other device I tested on (Galaxy, Pixel, Xiomi) only in Huawei. Would have been good to know that you cannot use a colon : as a file name in Huawei.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add permissions in your Manifest file

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder

Comment: I have permission to record audio, but not to write external storage. In that sample they don't use permission to write external storage and I'm getting the same error even when I try to save the file in a directory private to my app - getFilesDir() - where I definetely not need permission to write external storage

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong! Isn't the private to your app directory exist in your phone storage? Moreover above android 6.0 you have to check permission in run time.

Comment: I check record audio permission on runtime. The directory exists because I use it to store and retrieve correctly other stuff